# PhoneSateIntentReceiver code example in android

Tags: android, call, broadcastreceiver

Considering the following code snippet :

```
public class MyBroadReceiver  extends PhoneSateIntentReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context,Intent i ){

        if(i.action == Intent.CALL_ACTION){
           //some code here 
         }
     }
}
```

Assuming that `notifyPhoneCallState` has been called to enable `MyBroadReceiver`  to receive about the phone call state, in which cases the above code will be executed?

Please suggest if you have some views over this.

Comment: Is this question from [UpWork](https://www.upwork.com/) "Android Programming Test"? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in which cases the above code will be executed

Never, since there is no `notifyPhoneCallState()` in the Android SDK, and so your app will never compile.

Also, there is no `PhoneSateIntentReceiver`, or even a `PhoneStateIntentReceiver`, and so your app will never compile.